# Which collation should I use to store these country names in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I am trying to store a list of countries in a mySQL database.

I am having problems storing (non English) names like these:

- São Tomé and Príncipe
- República de El Salvador

They are stored with strange characters in the db, (and therefore output strangely in my HTML pages).

I have tried using different combinations of collations for the database and the MySQL connection collation:

The "obvious" setting was to use utf8_unicode_ci  for both the databse and the connection information. To my utter surprise, that did not solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**[Edit]**

It turns out the problem is not to do with collation, but rather encoding, as pointed out by the col. I notice that at the command line, I can type two separate commands:

```
SET NAMES utf8

followed by

[QUERY]
```

where [QUERY] is my SQL statment to retrieve the names, and that works (names are no longer mangled). However, when I do the same thing programatically (i.e. through code), I still get the mangled names. I tried combining the two statements like this:

```
SET NAMES utf8; [QUERY]
```

at the command line, again, this returned the correct strings. Once again, when I tried the same statements through code, I got wrong values.

This is a snippet of what my code looks like:

```
$mysqli = self::get_db_connection();
$mysqli->query('SET NAMES utf8');

$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM country';

$results = self::fetch($sql);

the fetch method is:

    private static function fetch($query)
    {
        $rows = array();

        if (!empty($query))
        {
            $mysqli = self::get_db_connection();

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
            {
                self::logError($mysqli->connect_error);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
                {
                    if(is_object($result)){
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                            $rows[] = $row;
                        $result->close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return $rows;
    }
```

Can anyone spot what I may be doing thats wrong?

Just to clarify, the HTTP headers in the page are set correctly
'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'

so thats not the issue here.

Comment: are you sure that it didn't solve the problem? Did you make sure that your input was encoded properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of  fact, `collation` affects nothing of a kind. it's a thing used for ordering and comparison, not recoding.
It is `encoding` responsible for the characters itself.

So, your problem comes not from the table collation but from the connection encoding

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

query should solve the problem, at leas for the *newly inserted data*

Answer (score 1):

if you use uf8 everywhere*, it will work - seems like you forgot anything

*everywhere means: *for your database-collation and -connection, for your (php?) script files and for the pages that are sent to the browser (by setting a meta-tag or, better, set an uftf-8-header)*

Comment: I would throw in "accept-charset='UTF-8'" in the form tag as well.

Comment: ok, so if I send the page in utf8, the browser is guaranteed to reply in possible post-data in utf8?